# How would one clone nova:posts in Telescope Nova?

Tags: meteor, telescope

Basically what I've done is duplicate the "nova:posts" folder into "custom-nova-posts" and placed this new package into the "packages" directory.

Then I commented out "nova:posts" in ".meteor/packages" and placed "custom-nova-posts" right below it. I then went in to the "package.js" file for "custom-nova-posts" and changed the "name" to match what was in ".meteor/packages".

The app then threw the error "Error: A method named '/posts/insert' is already defined".

I then tried the same process with "nova:comments" and it threw the same error, replacing "posts" with "comments".

Answer (score 0):

That error usually means you're trying to define the same collection twice. So it sounds like the app is still loading the old `nova:posts`.

This is probably happening because *other* packages have dependencies on `nova:posts`.

What I would do is simply name your "custom-nova-posts" package `nova:posts` as well. (and rename `nova:posts` to `nova:posts-disabled` or something). Note that your *directory* can still be named "custom-nova-posts" to avoid Git conflicts, you only need to set the package name in `package.js`.